# Using promises in string replace

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to promises and I'm having issues.

I have a function that I want to be able to do a bunch of string replacements to the given text, a few which include a value returned from an api call.

```
parseText(text) {
  text.replace(/\n|\r\n|\r/g, ' ')
  .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
  .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
  .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
  .replace(/<#(C\w+)\|?(\w+)?>/g, (match, id, read) => {
    return apiMethod(id).then(resp => resp.name)
  })
  .then(newText => {
    return newText.replace(/(-\w+)>/g, (match, id) => {
      apiMethod(id).then(resp => resp.name)
    }
  });
}
```

How do I get the replace to work with the returned value of `apiMethod` promise?

Comment: do you have problem returning from this function? or do you problem parsing the text

Comment: Looks like you just want `return` prefixing the first line

Comment: @Phil Problem is, `.replace` expects the callback function to return a replacement *synchronously*

Comment: Ah, right. Of course. Time to modify `String.prototype`?

Comment: Right, I can put the return in there, but my problem is the replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create an array of Promises for each request, call `Promise.all` on the array, and then create an object indexed by the `id` (the first group in your regex). Then, call `.replace` again, and substitute with the the appropriate indexed key. Because you have to asynchronously replace more than once, put it into its own function to make your code DRY:

```
const asyncReplace = async (str, regex) => {
  const promises = [];

  // does not actually replace anything, just builds the promises:
  str.replace(regex, (match, id, read) => {
    promises.push(apiMethod(id).then(resp => [id, resp.name]));
  });
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  const replacements = results.reduce((a, [id, name]) => {
    a[id] = name;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return str.replace(regex, (match, id, read) => replacements[id]);
}

parseText(text) {
  const str = text.replace(/\n|\r\n|\r/g, ' ')
  .replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
  .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
  .replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
  return asyncReplace(str, /<#(C\w+)\|?(\w+)?>/g)
    .then((str2) => asyncReplace(str2, /<#(C\w+)\|?(\w+)?>/g))
}
```

Live snippet:

```js
// encloses the match in underscores
const apiMethod = substr => Promise.resolve('_' + substr + '_');

const asyncReplace = async (str, regex) => {
  const promises = [];

  // does not actually replace anything, just builds the promises:
  str.replace(regex, (match, id, read) => {
    promises.push(apiMethod(id).then(resp => [id, resp]));
  });
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  const replacements = results.reduce((a, [id, name]) => {
    a[id] = name;
    return a;
  }, {});
  return str.replace(regex, (match, id, read) => replacements[id]);
}

function parseText(text) {
  // put underscores around every space...
  return asyncReplace(text, /( )/g)
  // ...twice:
    .then((str2) => asyncReplace(str2, /( )/g))
}
parseText('foo bar baz')
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: I don't think they can be run in parallel considering OP feeds the result of the first async operation into the second. Though now I think I'm misunderstanding your answer :)

Comment: Ah, the second asynchronous `.replace` was edited into the question, time to fix my code

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I have more than one promise in the chain so I wanted to make sure to portray that if it ends up being a different answer.

Comment: I have it feeding into the next one because that was my guess. I really just want a bunch of replaces done on a string, with a few values coming from promises